# Errors Constructing Innerjoins

Tags: php, mysqli, inner-join

I'm having a little problem with getting my innerjoin to work.. Well, i'm sure that this is the offending line, because my binds, and fetch_array seems to be in order.

Here is my code:

```
$GetQuestion = $STD->prepare("
SELECT Users.ID, SecurityQuestion.Question, SecurityQuestion.Answer, SecurityQuestion.Show
FROM Users AS Users 
INNER JOIN SecurityQuestion AS SecurityQuestion
ON Users.ID = SecurityQuestion.UserID WHERE Users.Username=?");

$GetQuestion->bind_param("s", $_GET['RecoverUsername']);
$GetQuestion->execute();
$Results = $GetQuestion->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Error given is:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_array() in /var/www/New/ForgotPassword.php on line 47
```

But this structure is working throughout my code when i'm working with arrays.

Comment: If you are SURE it's your innerjoin, then your DB Structure for the two tables you are running your query on should be published.

Comment: I don't work with mysqli, but the PHP docs don't seem to list a method `mysqli_stmt::fetch_array()`: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-stmt.php

Comment: Do you need the `AS` keyword in this case as you are not changing the name.

Comment: @WaleedKhan http://us2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: @EdHeal is it possible to have a where clause in an innerjoin?

Comment: @user1968541 You don't *have* a `mysqli_result`. You have a `mysqli_stmt`.

Comment: @WaleedKhan so `fetch_array` with `query()` and `fetch()` with `prepared` statements?

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that the method you are trying to access does not exist, which in this case is: `mysqli_stmt::fetch_array()`.  Instead you should be utilizing [`mysqli_stmt::fetch()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php).

Comment: `$InnerJoinArray = $InnerJoinQuery->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);` -- This is more or less the same thing, using `fetch_array` and it seems to work without an error.

Comment: You are referencing the wrong method.  You are using `mysqli_stmt`, not `mysqli_result`, which makes your assumption invalid.  If you wish  to use the latter method then please refer to the example in the docs, as you have referenced.

Comment: Second question, is it valid to use a where clause in an innerjoin?